# How to set multiple properties in CSS?

Tags: qt, stylesheet, qtstylesheets, qlineedit

I've created CSS for a LineEdit.

**LineEdit.cpp**

```
void MyLineEdit::initStyleSheet()
{
  QString css = Css::instance().css( m_element );
  setProperty( "style", "normal" );
  setStyleSheet( css );
}
```

I have a separate .css file for style:

**MyLineEdit.css**

```
....
MyLineEdit[style="Normal"]:focus
{
    border: 1px solid red;
}

MyLineEdit[style="Normal"]:disabled
{
    border: 1px solid gray;
    background: gray;
}
```

Now there is one weird requirement: `MyLineEdit` should have a method called `setNoFrame`, in this function we set one more property for it, and this property is valid for only state `disabled`.

This is what I did:

```
MyLineEdit::setNoFrame()
{
  setProperty("noFrame","true");
  initSyleSheet();
}
```

And this is my updated .css data

```
....
MyLineEdit[style="Normal"]:focus
{
  border: 1px solid red;
}

MyLineEdit[style="Normal"]:disabled
{
  border: 1px solid gray;
  background: gray;
}

MyLineEdit[style="Normal", noFrame="true"]:disabled
{
  border: none;
  background: gray;
}
```

It doesn't work as I expected, the border is still there for state `disabled` and `noFrame = true`. Do I have mistake in combining properties for CSS above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're *really, really* close. Try

```
MyLineEdit[style="Normal"][noFrame="true"]:disabled
{
  border: none;
  background: gray;
}
```

From the CSS2 docs (which [Qt StyleSheets supports](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html#selector-types)):

> Multiple attribute selectors can be used to refer to several attributes of an element, or even several times to the same attribute.
>
> Here, the selector matches all SPAN elements whose "hello" attribute has exactly the value "Cleveland" and whose "goodbye" attribute has exactly the value "Columbus":
>
> ```
> span[hello="Cleveland"][goodbye="Columbus"] { color: blue; }
> ```